# CVE fields vulnerable_products vs whats in configuration

Tags: cve

I would like to understand better the structure of the CVE.

(For example) in [CVE-2018-19081](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2018-19081), `vulnerable_products` mention product `Opticam i5`. like so:

```
"vulnerable_products": [
    "cpe:2.3:o:opticam:i5_application_firmware:2.21.1.128:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
    "cpe:2.3:o:opticam:i5_system_firmware:1.5.2.11:*:*:*:*:*:*:*"
],
```

but the configuration nodes also mention product `Foscam c2`. like so:

```
"children": [
                {
                    "operator": "OR",
                    "cpe_match": [
                        {
                            "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:o:foscam:c2_application_firmware:2.72.1.32:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
                            "vulnerable": true
                        },
                        {
                            "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:o:foscam:c2_system_firmware:1.11.1.8:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
                            "vulnerable": true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "operator": "OR",
                    "cpe_match": [
                        {
                            "cpe23Uri": "cpe:2.3:h:foscam:c2:-:*:*:*:*:*:*:*",
                            "vulnerable": false
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
```

So why is c2 not mentioned in `vunerable_products` and why is it mentioned in the configuration?

I've seen many CVEs that their configuration mentions products that are missing from the field vulnerable_products.
What is the purpose of the configuration if not to specify the vulnerable products?

Comment: they appear to be different products: opticam and foscam and they are listed in the `OR`

Comment: Actually opticam and foscam are the vendors. but yes. Still the question why information from the configuration is not in the vulnerable_products

Comment: They are not "missing", there's a range of vulnerable products, and it would appear that they are grouped based on product line.

Comment: can you link where you got the data you posted?

Comment: The data is part of a json available from NVD here
https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/json/cve/1.1/nvdcve-1.1-2018.json.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have listed an NVD JSON 1.1 snippet, and the answer is in the [schema](https://csrc.nist.gov/schema/nvd/feed/1.1-Beta/nvd_cve_feed_json_1.1_beta.schema).

The `vulnerable` field is `required` as it is the primary product affected.

The `configurations` field is not required, and as the schema states:

```
Defines the set of product configurations for a NVD applicability statement.
```

As you point out, the Opticam products are vulnerable, and the `configurations` section lists other closely related products/configurations that are similarly affected.

Why are they separated? Since CVEs are product-based, it makes sense not to lump multiple products into the primary key for the CVE, but to add the related products in a child node.

Comment: Great thanks. Do you know where can I find more info about that structure? For example I would like to understand what it means that the configuration's node has vulnerable = false